# React-Native custom font only works for bold weight

Tags: android, react-native

I have added custom font([kalam](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Kalam)) to my project through react-native link.This is how my android file directory with fonts looks like: 
[image]

This works when i use bold as font weight:

```
var style = {

  fontFamily:'kalam',
  fontWeight:'bold',

}
```

[image]

But if i use any fontWeight or without fontWeight `kalam` font does not apply:

```
var style = {

  fontFamily:'kalam',

}
```

[image]

Can someone tell why kalam fonts does not apply to regular text?

Comment: `fontFamily: 'kalam_regular'`? The fontFamily name depends on the full font name on OS X.

Comment: Huh i have thought that i have tried that...,thanks Andrew!